# Catching search matched term in to a variable and linking to other document

Tags: javascript, regex, pdf

please have my below code :

```
var pdf_files=["a1.pdf","a2.pdf","a3.pdf"];
for(k=0;k<pdf_files.length;k++)
{
    app.Open("/C/mySource/"+pdf_files[k]); //open the respective file

    for(var i=0;i<this.numPages;i++)
    {
        //loop through the entire document
        numWords=this.getPageNumWords(i);
        var WordString="";

        for(var j=0;j<numWords;j++)
        {
            WordString=WordString+" "+this.getPageNthWord(i,j);
        }

        if(WordString.match(/[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] FIG [0-9]+/)) //regular expression to match a string like "24-50-44 FIG 11"
        {
            search.matchWholeWord=true;
            var myMatch=search.query(WordString.match(/[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] FIG [0-9]+/),"ActiveDoc");
            console.println(myMatch);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem that I am facing here is :
I am opening one pdf file, searching the particular string as per regular expression. on successful search, I am trying to display that matched string onto console. But this is not happening. I need your suggestion in this regard.
Please let me know whether it is possible to store matched string in variable or not, also whether it's possible to link the matched string to one other .pdf file?

Comment: PDF files typically do not contain their contents stored as plain text.

Comment: I have used javascript properties that store the content and parse it as per regular expression.. I am not understanding where I am going wrong... ex getPageNumWords and getPageNthWord.. I have used that catch total no of words till last page and then search further as per regular expression..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regex capturing groups to capture the content you want. You can use this regex:

```
([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} FIG [0-9]+)
```

With a code like this:

```
var re = /([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} FIG [0-9]+)/g; 
var str = 'YOUR TEXT';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: var re = /([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} FIG [0-9]+)/g; 
var str = 'YOUR TEXT'; //here I need to pass .pdf file as input..

the regular expression should match to text from pdf file...
the matched string need to be linked to file that is named with dash(-) removed from matched string.

Comment: @MohammedJamadar you have to put *WordString*

Comment: @MohammedJamadar does my answer solved your question?

Comment: I have used WordString, please suggest me if any correction that i need to do there... I didn't get what you are telling...

Comment: I neeD to search pdf file for regex string, if its found, store that found string in one variable and link that string to a file in the same folder of pdf file..